# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 30 and 5

Tags: python, keras

When I try to compile the program I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a6b0a9d5d560> in <cell line: 25>()
     23 ])
     24 model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer="Adam")
---> 25 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30,
     26                     validation_data=(X_vaild, y_vaild))
```

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1322, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1303, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1081, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1139, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 268, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 1608, in mean_squared_error
        return backend.mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 30 and 5 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_11/dense_22/Relu, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,30], [?,5]..
```

I am attaching the program code below:

```
data_array = np.array([[2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5], [3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5], [3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5], [4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6], [4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5]])

target_array = np.array([[3, 3.5, 4, 4.5,5], [3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5], [4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6], [4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5], [5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7]])

array1 = {'data': data_array, 'target': target_array}

class array1:

  data = array1["data"]

  target = array1["target"]

obiect = array1()

X_train, X_vaild, y_train, y_vaild = train_test_split(
    obiect.data, obiect.target)

model = keras.models.Sequential([

    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),

])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer="Adam")

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30,
                    validation_data=(X_vaild, y_vaild))
```

Please help because the error is long and difficult to read. I looked through similar topics but unfortunately I did not find a solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but it looks like data_array / target_array has 5 dimensions, but you use 30 in `keras.layers.Dense(`, and it must be equal.

Comment: ^^ Thanks for help